# How to change the configuration of max results bq ls?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to change the configuration of max results? 
    bq ls

```
bq ls
```

only list 50 results.

I have to use

bq ls --max_results=300

to list more results.

How to change the configuration file so I can increase the max results default value?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Bash? You might be able to use this idea: https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name.

Comment: Garrrgh! Beat me to it @ElliottBrossard. I was literally just testing it ;-)

Comment: Post an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [set your own default values for the command-line flags](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags) that you will use with the `bq` CLI tool. They are specified in the `.bigqueryrc` configuration file, which is generally located in the path `$HOME/.bigqueryrc`.

Once you have identified that file (you can create your own if you want, and then point to it using the `BIGQUERYRC` environment variable), you can edit it and add the default value for the `max_results` flag, as in:

```
# This entry already existed in my file, so add the flag below
credential_file = <DIRECTORY_TO_CREDENTIALS>

[ls]
--max_results=300
```

Between brackets you have to add the specific `bq` command that you want to tune, and then below the flag whose default value you want to set, in the format `--<FLAG>=<VALUE>`.

The configuration file `.bigqueryrc` is read every single time a `bq` command is run, so changes will be updated automatically.